# C++ to VB.NET Conversion with Residual << and >> Remaining in Math Statements

Tags: c++, math, operators, vb.net-2010, logical-operators

I converted some C++ code to VB.NET but there is residual use of ">>" and "<<" being used during the workflow which is throwing me off.  How can I get rid of the << and >> in the example loops below and rewrite them in VB.NET without << and >>:

```
  For i As UInteger = q + 1 To L
     X(i) = X(i - q) Xor (X(i - q) >> CInt(q))
     For j As UInteger = 1 To q - 1
       X(i) = X(i) Xor (((b >> (q - 1 - j)) And 1) * X(i - j))
     Next j
  Next i
```

And other uses of << such as:

```
  For i As UInteger = 1 To L 
    X(i) = 1 << (32 - i)
  Next i
```

Mathematically, I don't what C++ is doing with the << and >>.

Comment: Those are [bit shift operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are bit shift operations, and you can leave them.  They are the same in VB .NET.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2d9yb87a.aspx